# Is the clang serialized AST portable?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using the python bindings to walk the clang AST...
When I encounter an error, I would like to dump the AST to a file, so that I can later load it from that file and debug the walker.

This works fine, if I dump and then load using the TranslationUnit.save() and Index.read() bindings, however this does not work if I move the AST file between platforms Linux -> Windows or Windows -> Linux.

Is this expected?
Is there a way to make the AST files "portable"?

Comment: did you compare the AST files generated in Linux and Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Not "portable" if you have some template C++ code that is accepted by MSVC, but typically diagnosed by Clang as invalid.

From [Clang Documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html):

> Third, MSVC accepts some C++ code that Clang will typically diagnose as invalid. When these constructs are present in widely included system headers, Clang attempts to recover and continue compiling the user’s program. Most parsing and semantic compatibility tweaks are controlled by -fms-compatibility and -fdelayed-template-parsing, and they are a work in progress.

Compare your saved AST files to check if they have the same nodes (the raw pointer address could be different). If not, fixed with the mentioned flags `-fms-compatibility`, `-fdelayed-template-parsing`.